# Кнопка F5 все равно сохраняет на базу

Tags: php, mysql

Сделал страницу, с которой через форму данные сохраняются в базе данных после нажатия на кнопку отправить. Для приема данных из формы я написал, как полагается, код следующего смысла: "если кнопка отправить нажималась, то принять данные для обработки и сохранения в базе данных".

Но у меня получается, когда нажимаю кнопку отправить, данные сохраняются, как и положено, но потом нажимаю F5 для перезагрузки страницы и те же данные сохраняются еще раз. А мне это не надо!  Помогите разобраться в чем тут дело...

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['save'])) {
    if (empty($_GET['title'])) {
        echo "Введите название";
    }

    elseif (empty($_GET['description'])) {
        echo "Введите описание";
    } elseif (empty($_GET['content'])) {
        echo "Введите содержимое";
    } else {
        $title       = $_GET['title'];
        $description = $_GET['description'];
        $img_path    = $_GET['img_path'];
        $content     = $_GET['content'];
        $date        = date("Y-m-d");
        $query       = "Insert Into news (title,description,img_path,date,content) Values ('$title','$description','$img_path','$date','$content')";
        $result      = mysql_query($query);
        if ($result == true) {
            echo "Вы успешно добавили новую новост!";
        } else {
            echo "Непредвиденная ошибка!";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

-

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <p>
        <label>название:</label>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="auto-focus"
        />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Описание:</label>
        <input type="text" name="description" id="description"
        class="auto-hint" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Путь к Images:</label>
        <input name="img_path" type="file" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Дата :</label>
        <input name="date" type="datetime-local" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="message">Содержимое:</label>
        <textarea cols="80" rows="4" id="message" name="content"
        class="auto-hint"></textarea>
    </p>
    <p>
        <button type="submit" name="save">Сохранить</button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Почему при обновлении страницы все равно сохраняет

Comment: Помогите пожплуйста что я нето делаю

Comment: Вы уже вчера задавали этот вопрос:
http://hashcode.ru/questions/99962/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=99979#99979

Comment: знаю но я не получил ответа

Comment: Там первый ответ, как это делается правильно, тоже самое тут пишет @Александр Смага.

З.Ы. или вы ждете ответа "К сожалению, тут ничего нельзя сделать, придется с этим смирится".

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на жизненный цикл страницы:

Когда вы загружаете страницу, сначала происходит просто ее отображение.

При нажатии кнопки отправки данных с формы, она загружается второй раз. При этом данные записываются прямо в *URL*, т.к. выбран метод отправки данных *GET*.

Поэтому, когда вы нажимаете <kbd>F5</kbd>, происходит снова переход по *URL*, в котором уже есть данные из формы. Естественно, ваш код тут же исправно сохраняет их в базу данных )

Comment: Да я все вижу но как надо сохранять???

Comment: Как уже было сказано - попробуйте разбить функционал на 2 страницы. На мой взгляд - это не самый идеальный вариант, но вам подойдет. Сама страница с формой в одном файле, обработчик сохранения в другом. Собственно, результат сохранения, даже сообщение об ошибке можно снова возвращать исходной странице, и та его будет отображать. В этом случае автоматического сохранения при каждом F5 не будет происходить.

Comment: И да, возьмите за правило проверять существование всех необходимых данных и проводить их очистку и приведение к типу, если это необходимо. Сильно поможет в дальнейшей жизни.

Answer (score 0):

Идеально писать систему из 3 реквестов.

1. Отображаем форму
2. Пытаемся сохранить данные
3. Если получилось сохранить редиректим на 3й request, если не вышло(имеются ошибки) на 1.

как то так...

И вообще у вас не очень надежный код!

У вас из переменных на *isset* проверяется только `save`, т.е., если других переменных не будет найдено, то будет *warning* и совсем не безопасный запрос в базу!

Используйте `mysql_real_escape_string` и приведение к типу (пишу конкретно по этому случаю).

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/79070/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8